# How to execute something as a root user (initially) for an otherwise non-root user container?

Tags: docker

I want to sync the host machine's user/group with the docker machine to enable (developers) to edit the files inside or outside the container. There are some ideas like this: [Handling Permissions with Docker Volumes](https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/) which creates a new user.

I would like to try a similar approach, but instead of creating a new user, I would like to modify the existing user using `usermod`:

```
usermod -d /${tmp} docker # avoid `usermod` from modifying permissions automatically.
usermod -u "${HOST_USER_ID}" docker
groupmod -g "${HOST_GROUP_ID}" docker
usermod -d ${HOME} docker
```

This idea seems to work, but when the container is run as docker user (which is what I want), `usermod` complains that "this user has a process running and so it can't change the user id".

If add `sudo`, it will change the user id, but it will break on the next `sudo` will the following exception: `sudo: unknown uid 1000: who are you?` as a consequence of side-stepping the above problem.

```
sudo usermod -d /${tmp} docker
sudo usermod -u "${HOST_USER_ID}" docker
sudo groupmod -g "${HOST_GROUP_ID}" docker # `sudo: unknown uid 1000: who are you?`
sudo usermod -d ${HOME} docker # `sudo: unknown uid 1000: who are you?`
```

Is it possible to run something as a `root` when the container is started, along with a bootstrap script as a normal user? It seems like the Dockerfile's `CMD` doesn't executes two commands; nor can I club multiple commands into one script sine I need to run as two users - or can I? I know I can create a different image, but wondering if there are cleaner alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start your container as `root`, allow the `ENTRYPOINT` script to perform any changes you want, and then switch to an unprivileged user when you execute the container `CMD`.  E.g., use an `ENTRYPOINT` script something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

usermod -d /${tmp} docker
usermod -u "${HOST_USER_ID}" docker
groupmod -g "${HOST_GROUP_ID}" docker

exec runuser -u docker -- "$@"
```

If you don't have the `runuser` command, you can get similar behavior using `su`.

Comment: Ah thanks, @larsks! So combining `exec` and `runuser` is the key point. I thought about both of them independently, but couldn't work it out - the combination might work though; let me try it out. The reason I want to run it as normal user is to avoid exiting twice.

Comment: I had to make that `exec runuser -u docker -- "$@"` to make it support `CMD ["/bin/bash", "--init-file", "bootstrap.sh"]`. Without the `--`, only `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` worked.

Comment: Good idea re: adding the `--` to prevent options from getting eaten by `runuser`. I've updated the answer to include that.